# Update query: Unterminated string constant error asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am working in asp classic. I am new to asp and it's syntax seems confusing to me.

I have this code to update data in a table named jeanmeasure.

What is wrong with this query? It gives the following error:

now my code is

```
Dim m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m1d,m2d,m3d,m4d,m5d,m6d,m7d,m8d,m9d 
m1 = Request.QueryString("m1")
m2 = Request.QueryString("m2")
m3 = Request.QueryString("m3")
m4 = Request.QueryString("m4")
m5 = Request.QueryString("m5")
m6 = Request.QueryString("m6")
m7 = Request.QueryString("m7")
m8 = Request.QueryString("m8")
m9 = Request.QueryString("m9")

m1d = Request.QueryString("m1d")
m2d = Request.QueryString("m2d")
m3d = Request.QueryString("m3d")
m4d = Request.QueryString("m4d")
m5d = Request.QueryString("m5d")
m6d = Request.QueryString("m6d")
m7d = Request.QueryString("m7d")
m8d = Request.QueryString("m8d")
m9d = Request.QueryString("m9d")


sql =" UPDATE jeanmeasure SET m1 = "&m1&" , m2 = ,"&m2&", m3 = "&m3&", m4 = "&m4&", m5 = "&m5&",m6 = "&m6&",m7 = "&m7&",m8 = "&m8&",m9 = "&m9&",m1d = "&m1d&", m2d = "&m2d&", m3d = "&m3d&", m4d = "&m4d&",m5d = "&m5d&",m6d = "&m6d&",m7d = "&m7d&", m8d = "&m8d&", m9d = "&m9d&" WHERE id = 1 "
    Response.Write(sql)
     dbobj.execute(sql)
```

and the error is
syntax erro
 near '' = 'm1 , m2 = ,m2, m3 = m3, m4 = , m5 = m5,m6 = m6,m7 = m7,m8 = m8,m9 = m9,m1d ' at line 1

Comment: You are completely open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), for one. You should use [parameterized queries](http://www.userfriendlythinking.com/Blog/BlogDetail.asp?p1=7013&p2=119&p7=3001). Did you check the value of `up` before it gets to SQL Server?

Comment: forget about that right now .. i need to fix this query @Oded

Comment: Did you check the _actual_ value of the query before you execute it? Look at that (possibly post it here) - that's where it is wrong.

Comment: the query is not correct then how can i check the value of up

Comment: Output it to the page? Debug through and check its value?

Comment: response.write(up) does not output any thing

Comment: Are you outputting it just before executing the query? Did you look at the page source?

Answer (score 1):

look at

```
m2 = ,"&m2&"
```

the comma is at the wrong position must be

```
m2 = "&m2&",
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should be: m1 = '"&m1&"', m2 = '"&m2&"', ...